# I want to disable particular days of week on calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have calendar. What I want to do is I want to disable current week of Saturday after 4 P.M. of Wednesday and week of Thursday after 4 P.M. of Monday.

Currently All Saturdays are being disabled I want only particular week saturday to be disable.

Link where I want to do that functionality: https://plateup.co.nz/cart

```
<script>
  $( function() {

    //Create array for next 7 days
    var day1 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 1).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day2 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 2).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day3 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 3).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day4 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 4).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day5 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 5).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day6 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 6).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var day7 = parseInt(moment().add('days', 7).format('DDMMYYYY'));
    var next7Days = [day1, day2, day3, day4, day5, day6, day7];

    var dayOfWeek = moment().format('dddd');

    var dateToday = new Date();

    console.log(dayOfWeek);


    if(dayOfWeek == 'Sunday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }else if(dayOfWeek == 'Monday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }else if(dayOfWeek == 'Tuesday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }else if(dayOfWeek == 'Wednesday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }else if(dayOfWeek == 'Thursday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;      
    }else if (dayOfWeek == 'Friday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }else if(dayOfWeek == 'Saturday'){
      var datesToDisable = 3;
    }

    if (dayOfWeek == 'Wednesday' && dateToday.getHours()>=16) {
        var isWedAfternoon = true;
        var disablesat = true;
    }else{
        var isWedAfternoon = false;
        var disablesat = false;
    }


    if (dayOfWeek == 'Monday' && dateToday.getHours()>=16) {
        var isMondayAfternoon = true;
        var disablethu = true;
    }else{
        var isMondayAfternoon = false;
        var disablethu = false;
    }




    // User date picker Jquery ui
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        minDate: datesToDisable,
        maxDate: 18,
        dateFormat: 'ddmmyyyy',
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        //defaultDate:+7,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
          var day = date.getDay();


          if (disablesat) {
              var daysToDisable = (day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 5 && day != 6);
          }else if(disablethu){
              var daysToDisable = (day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 4 && day != 5);
          }else{
              var daysToDisable = (day != 0 && day != 1 && day != 2 && day != 3 && day != 5);
          }

          return [daysToDisable];


        },
         onSelect: function(_date) {
           var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); // Retrieve selected date
           var reformattedDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', myDate);
           var dateNumber = parseInt($.datepicker.formatDate('ddmmyy', myDate));
            var dayOfWeek = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD", myDate);

           $('#attributeDay').val(dayOfWeek);
           $('#attributeDate').val(reformattedDate);



           if (jQuery.inArray(dateNumber, next7Days)!='-1') {
             $('#dateCheck').html('is in next 7 days');
             $('#attributeFutureDeliver').val('false');
           } else {
             $('#attributeFutureDeliver').val('true');
             $('#dateCheck').html('is NOT in next 7 days')
           }
        }

      });


    $('.checkout_btn').click(function() {
      if ($('#attributeDate').val() == '') {
        alert("Please pick a delivery date"); 
        return false;
      }
      else {
        $(this).submit();
      }
    });

  } );
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your statement: *"What I want to do is I want to disable current week of Saturday after 4 P.M. of Wednesday and week of Thursday after 4 P.M. of Monday."*

My understanding is: "If current day is Monday and time is post 4pm, disable current week's Thursday" and 
"If current day is Wednesday and time is post 4pm, disable current week's Saturday"

But when I tried executing your code:

1. Because of minDate (which is always 3) and maxDate (which is hard-coded to 18), 3rd date to 18th date from current date will be enabled, all other dates are disabled.
2. In addition to these, the logic in the 'beforeShowDay' function will disable all other days except Thursday and Saturday.

Coming back to your question - *"I want only particular week saturday to be disable."*

**Here is example of how to disable current week's Saturday:**
[Disable particular day in current week(jsfiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/sohanchandak/bnd7ck3o/)

```
$('#date1').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "m/d/yy",
    beforeShowDay: function (currentDate) {
        var currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
        // Saturday is 6th day of the week
        if(currentDay != 6) return [true];
        var todaysDate = new Date();
        var numberOfDaysToAdd = 6 - todaysDate.getDay();
        // reach current week's Saturday
        todaysDate.setDate(todaysDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
        return [currentDate.getDate() != todaysDate.getDate()]
    }
});
```

I will be able to help more on this if you post all your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and help. My issue is solved now thank you. Will let you know if any help needed in future